# Quoting non-contiguous paragraphs

Tags: punctuation, quotations, citation

How do I quote two non-contiguous paragraphs from a longer article? I want to be clear that they're non-contiguous, but not have an editorial interlude between them. Here's an example quotation from [an article by Clay Shirky](http://www.shirky.com/weblog/2014/01/there-isnt-enough-money-to-keep-educating-adults-the-way-were-doing-it/), with how I *want* to format it:

> Over the decades, though, [higher education has] behaved like an embezzler who starts by taking only what he means to replace, but ends up extracting so much that embezzlement becomes the system. [...]
>
> When the economic support from the Golden Age began to crack, we tenured faculty couldn’t be forced to share much of the pain. Our jobs were secure, so rather than forgo raises or return to our old teaching loads, we either allowed or encouraged those short-term fixes—rising tuition, larger student bodies, huge introductory lectures.

I thought about moving the bracketed ellipsis to its own line, which seems more proper but looks clunky.

I'm also interested in how you might quote this if it weren't a block quote -- specifically, should you close the first paragraph with a quotation mark or not?

(Also, this is in an email, not an academic paper, so I'm worried about readability rather than about adhering to an official style guide.)